# Attractors in Duffing equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The Duffing equation in its full form is

$$\ddot{x} + \delta \dot{x} -\alpha x + \beta x^3 = \gamma \cos(\omega t)$$

Now for specific values of the parameters several attractors exist (or not). Let's assume that $\alpha = \beta = \omega = 1$, $\delta = 0.15$, while $\gamma = 0.2445$. For these values of the parameters the system has two fixed-point attractors and a period-$3$ attractor. The period-$1$ attractors are located at about $(0.815, 0.242)$ and $(−0.933, 0.299)$. The period-$3$ attractor is located at about $(−1.412,−0.137)$, $(−0.354,−0.614)$, and $(0.645,−0.464)$.

My question is the following: How do we obtain the values of the positions of the attractors? Is there a theoretical way or is it done purely numerically? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The best analytical approach is in this case to use averaging techniques for the full nonlinear, weakly damped and weakly forced Duffing equation (i.e. $\beta$ is order 1, but both $\delta$ and $\gamma$ are reasonably small). The technique of averaging is well explained [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Duffing_oscillator#The_weakly_forced_system:_nonlinear_resonance) for small $\beta$, which makes the situation a bit easier, as the 'basis functions' to average over are well-known trigonometric functions.
If $\beta= 1$, those 'basis functions' or 'generating functions' for the unperturbed systems are Jacobi elliptic functions, see [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22) for more information. The averaging technique works exactly the same, only the integrals become a bit more cumbersome.

In I Kovacic and M J Brennan (eds), *The Duffing Equation: Nonlinear Oscillators and their Behaviour*, Wiley (2011), ISBN: 978-0-470-71549-9, this is mentioned on [page 82](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f6oZ0cwjTs8C&lpg=PR25&ots=8SiJ0KmteL&dq=duffing%20elliptic&lr&pg=PA82#v=onepage&q&f=false). In particular, they give an extensive reference list to find results obtained using this technique and other techniques. To summarise: look at references [15-33] in Kovacic & Brennan, which are listed [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f6oZ0cwjTs8C&lpg=PR25&ots=8SiJ0KmteL&dq=duffing%20elliptic&lr&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q&f=false).